# Logging JSON values using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have a JSON feed and i'm simply trying to print out some values.

My Javascript below sort of works. But it doesn't look very 'correct'. Is there a better way of doing this please?

**JSON**

```
{
   "info":[
      {
         "lon":-2.1,
         "lat":55.2
      },
      {
         "lon":-2.12,
         "lat":55.23
      }
   ]
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var jsonURL = "url here";

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json1) {
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, data){

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    data.lat, data.lon);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng
            });

            marker.setMap(map);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you running into any sort of issue that would make you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the "info" attribute exists and don't need a loop to get to it.  The inner loop looks good.

```
$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json1) {

        $.each(json1.info, function(key, data){

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    data.lat, data.lon);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng
            });

            marker.setMap(map);

        });
});
```